# Locate the closest image from the center of the screen Python, Pyautogui

Tags: pyautogui

I need help in locating the image, I just want it to locate the closest image from the center of the screen, I wrote something like this but it locates a random image and not the closest from the center and I don't know how to write it :(

```
 def nav_to_image(self, target_png):
        try:
            position = (pt.locateCenterOnScreen(target_png, confidence=.8))
            pt.moveTo(position[0], position[1], duration=self.speed)
            pt.click()
```